# Masters student used part of PhD student's work

Tags: thesis, plagiarism

I am a PhD student doing research in a university. I was working on a research project which would be part of my thesis and upon completion of some parts of it I submitted the draft manuscript to my supervisor. However, almost 1 year after I started the project, one Masters student joined our lab and started working with me.

As I was also helping him to write his Master's thesis, his thesis contained parts of my research manuscript with many exact texts and data written and obtained by me. I didn't/couldn't object to that at that time, neither did I approve him to submit that thesis with those data/texts. But, when he sent me the manuscript of the thesis (which contained texts/data written by me), I mailed him: "Nice, I will make some more corrections here and there". In the  thesis, he also  acknowledged me for my "support" in his research work, although he didn't specify.

The thing is, now I noticed that in his thesis it is declared that "This work is done by the Masters student independently and the results contained in the thesis has not been submitted for the award of any other degree elsewhere", which is also approved by my supervisor. The declaration made here is entirely wrong as he did not do the work independently (bulk of it was actually done by me) and the work was intended to be part of my phd thesis.

Now, I added many additional data and new research ideas to that research work and want to add it as my thesis chapter. My question is, should I seek permission from the Masters student to incorporate the parts of the data that were already incoporated in his thesis? There is clear evidence that the data and texts that he used in his thesis were not obtained or written by him originally, but were parts of a manuscript submitted by me to my supervisor almost 1 year before his joining. But still,  can he refuse or stop me from using that data? Also, will it be considred plagiarism if I use those data without his permission? Or plagiarism  is considered to be committed by him as his thesis contained parts of my manuscript?

Edit.
Also, can it be accused for helping someone to do plagiarism? All I did, was following my superviser's instructions-which I can't prove this way may be. But he did a similar thing before, where he used another student's research work into someone elses thesis, and the student complained about him to the higher authority. But the situation was handled internally, with no punishment for my superviser

I don't know how to manage this situation. I have to  include this work in my thesis as I have already published a paper based on this. But I can't alter or remove the parts of data that were included into the Masters' student's thesis

Comment: "I didn't/couldn't object to that at that time" I hope you have learned that you should object strongly. Discuss the issue with your advisor. You might need to rewrite parts of your thesis to be safe from accusations of plagiarism (wich could happen many years later, as some European politicians experienced).

Comment: @Roland Thank you for your suggestion. But can I be accused of plagiarism? The Master's thesis contains text and data written and obtained by me originally. There is clear evidence that I wrote those parts as I submitted a manuscript containing those texts and data to my supervisor almost 1 year before the student's joining. So, isn't technically the Masters student plagiarizing?

Comment: You have one witness. Unless they want to accuse the master's student of plagiarism and start the appropriate procedures at your institution, they probably are not willing to confirm this in writing. Thus, in many years, when your witness might not be available anymore, you have no way of prooving your account of what happened. Your main issue here is that both you and your advisor technically knew that the student plagiarized when you approved their thesis. Now you are in a mess that can only be solved by either creating additional work for you or by making your advisor look bad.

Comment: @Roland Thanks. Actually I can have the evidence even if my supervisor isn't available anymore, as I sent the manuscript to my supervisor by email at that time , The date of the email predates the student's joining. I still have the email  with me. I also didn't approve (or disapprove) the Master's thesis, as there was no such option for that in his dissertation. Only my  supervisor approved it. So yes,  may be any actions taken by me might make my supervisor look bad.

Comment: Time stamps of an email can be changed easily ...

Comment: O, I didn't know that.

Comment: @Roland  O, I didn't know that. Lets see..... There can be other evidences, e.g. the doctoral committee report. Also, many  parts of the work were done by me in a foreign country as part of collaborative project, where the master's student didn't go. Those had to be added in his thesis as certain parts of thesis (e.g. characterization and machine designing data) cannot be ommitted. But he clearly can't prove that he did those characterizations as he was not in that foreign lab.

Comment: All of that might proove that you didn't plagiarize but also that you knew of plagiarism and didn't do anything about it. I'm not sure I would want that on my record.

Comment: @Roland Thatz true. Anyway thanks for your advice and suggestions. It helped a lot :)